In Sinon, how do you assert a property/accessor was used before/after another test double?
Note: I will answer my own question, but if you have a better answer, I'll accept it over mine.
I have a function that looks like this:
  function systemUnderTest(func, param) {
    param.firstProperty = !param.firstProperty;
    func();
    param.secondProperty = !param.secondProperty;
  }

I would like to stub param and assert that param.firstProperty is assigned before func() is called. I would also like to check that func() is called before param.secondProperty is set.
Sinon comes with spy.calledBefore(anotherSpy) and this seems like the right tool for the job, but I'm not sure how to set up param, an object literal, to record the order in which its properties/accessors are used.
How do I set up param so I can call x.calledBefore(y) on its properties?

I know of two ways to achieve this and both come with trade-offs. One solution is more verbose but more flexible. The other solution is more concise but limited in its application.
Verbose, but works on getters, setters, and/or properties
  function systemUnderTest(func, param) {
    param.firstProperty = !param.firstProperty;
    func();
    param.secondProperty = !param.secondProperty;
  }

  it('tests order of setters', () => {
    // SETUP
    const param = {
      firstProperty: true, // 1
      secondProperty: true,
    };
    const firstPropertySetter = sinon.stub(); // 2
    sinon.stub(param, 'firstProperty').set(firstPropertySetter); // 3
    const secondPropertySetter = sinon.spy(); // 4
    sinon.stub(param, 'secondProperty').set(secondPropertySetter); // 5

    const aFunction = sinon.stub(
      {
        aFunction: () => {},
      },
      'aFunction'
    );

    // SUBJECT
    systemUnderTest(aFunction, param);

    // ASSERT
    expect(firstPropertySetter.calledBefore(aFunction)).toBeTrue(); // pass, as it should
    expect(firstPropertySetter.calledOnce).toBeTrue(); // pass, as it should

    expect(secondPropertySetter.calledBefore(aFunction)).toBeTrue(); // fail, as it should
  });

Notes:

This example uses properties inside param, but if param used getters/setters, this test would still function as desired.
sinon.stub() needs to be saved in a variable. Unfortunately, const firstPropertySetter = sinon.stub(param, 'firstProperty').set(sinon.stub()); will not work correctly because firstPropertySetter.called* will always return false/0. (I'd love to understand why.)
As mentioned earlier, this call to .set(...) works even though the object literal does not have a setter.
You can use sinon.spy() instead of sinon.stub() on this line if you prefer.
But you can't use sinon.spy() here: .set(...) does not exist on spy().

I learned of this solution from this GitHub comment.
Concise, but only works on getters and setters
  function systemUnderTest(func, param) {
    param.firstAccessor = !param.firstAccessor; // 1
    func();
    param.secondAccessor = !param.secondAccessor;
  }

  it('tests order of setters/getters', () => {
    // SETUP
    const param = {
      set firstAccessor(value) {}, // 2
      get firstAccessor() {
        return true;
      },
      set secondAccessor(value) {},
      get secondAccessor() {
        return true;
      },
    };
    const firstAccessor = sinon.spy(param, 'firstAccessor', ['get', 'set']); // 3
    const secondAccessor = sinon.spy(param, 'secondAccessor', ['get', 'set']);

    const aFunction = sinon.stub(
      {
        aFunction: () => {},
      },
      'aFunction'
    );

    // SUBJECT
    systemUnderTest(aFunction, param);

    // ASSERT
    expect(firstAccessor.set.calledBefore(aFunction)).toBeTrue(); // 4 // pass, as it should
    expect(firstAccessor.set.calledOnce).toBeTrue(); // pass, as it should

    expect(secondAccessor.set.calledBefore(aFunction)).toBeTrue(); // fail, as it should
  });

Notes:

I want to draw attention to the fact that I renamed these keys from *Property to *Accessor.

param must use getters and setters for this solution...

...if, for example, firstAccessor were a property, this line would error with: TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property firstAccessor as function.
Aside: I'm not sure why this error message says it's an "undefined property." That might be a mistake in the error message?
Also, this line must use sinon.spy(). sinon.stub()'s third argument does not accept an array of strings.

I want to draw attention to the fact that .set / .get is called on the spy to access the sinon API. e.g., firstAccessor.set.calledBefore() exists, firstAccessor.calledBefore does not.


I learned this solution from the official Sinon spy documentation. Search for "Using a spy to wrap property getter and setter" on that page to find another example.

This was tested with Sinon v17.
